# I have used SPFX Asset to create Field, Content Type and List for Office 365 Add-in

Tags: office-365, spfx, assets

In my solution Everything working fine except below two things.I have refer this [link](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/web-parts/get-started/provision-sp-assets-from-package) to create list

1. I am not able to remove title column from List
2. When I go to List Setting I can't see content type which I used to create a List

[image]

**Note**:- But When I tried to add this content type to list It looks like that it's already added. When I click on Item Content type it shows that it inherited from **Cost Center** content Type.
[image]

I have used below code

**package-solution.json**

```
{
    "solution": {
        "name": "practice",
        "id": "cd473f16-232e-418e-ba70-6c02ed46c704",
        "version": "1.0.1.9",
        "features": [{
          "title": "practice",
          "description": "practice solution to Create List and Site Content type on web",
          "id": "d46cd9d6-87fc-473b-a4c0-db9ad9162b64",
          "version": "1.0.0.0",
          "assets": {        
            "elementManifests": [
              "elements.xml"
            ],
            "elementFiles":[
              "schema.xml"
            ]
          }
        }]
      },
      "paths": {
        "zippedPackage": "solution/acco-practice.sppkg"
      }
    }
```

**elements.xml**

```
    <Field ID="{060E50AC-E9C1-4D3C-B1F9-DE0BCAC300F6}"
            Name="SPFxAmount"
            DisplayName="Amount"
            Type="Currency"
            Decimals="2"
            Min="0"
            Required="True"
            Group="SPFx Columns" />

    <Field ID="{943E7530-5E2B-4C02-8259-CCD93A9ECB18}"
            Name="SPFxCostCenter"
            DisplayName="Cost Center"
            Type="Choice"
            Required="FALSE"
            Group="SPFx Columns">
        <CHOICES>
        <CHOICE>Administration</CHOICE>
        <CHOICE>Information</CHOICE>
        <CHOICE>Facilities</CHOICE>
        <CHOICE>Operations</CHOICE>
        <CHOICE>Sales</CHOICE>
        <CHOICE>Marketing</CHOICE>
        </CHOICES>
    </Field>

    <ContentType ID="0x010042D0C1C200A14B6887742B6344675C8B" 
            Name="Cost Center" 
            Group="SPFx Content Types" 
            Inherits="FALSE"
            Description="Sample content types from web part solution">
        <FieldRefs>
            <RemoveFieldRef  ID="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}" Name="LinkTitle" />
            <FieldRef ID="{060E50AC-E9C1-4D3C-B1F9-DE0BCAC300F6}" /> 
            <FieldRef ID="{943E7530-5E2B-4C02-8259-CCD93A9ECB18}" />
        </FieldRefs>
    </ContentType> 

    <ListInstance 
            CustomSchema="schema.xml"
            FeatureId="00bfea71-de22-43b2-a848-c05709900100"
            Title="SPFx List" 
            Description="SPFx List"
            TemplateType="100"
            Url="Lists/SPFxList" >
    </ListInstance>
</Elements>
```

**Schema.xml**

```
<List xmlns:ows="Microsoft SharePoint" Title="SPFxList" EnableContentTypes="TRUE" FolderCreation="FALSE" Direction="$Resources:Direction;" Url="Lists/SPFxList" BaseType="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <MetaData>
    <ContentTypes>
      <ContentTypeRef Name="Cost Center"  ID="0x010042D0C1C200A14B6887742B6344675C8B" />
    </ContentTypes>
    <Fields></Fields>
    <Views>
      <View BaseViewID="1" Type="HTML" WebPartZoneID="Main" DisplayName="$Resources:core,objectiv_schema_mwsidcamlidC24;" DefaultView="TRUE" MobileView="TRUE" MobileDefaultView="TRUE" SetupPath="pages\viewpage.aspx" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/generic.png" Url="AllItems.aspx">
        <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
        <JSLink>clienttemplates.js</JSLink>
        <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
        <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
        <ViewFields>
          <FieldRef Name="SPFxAmount"></FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="SPFxCostCenter"></FieldRef>
        </ViewFields>
        <Query>
          <OrderBy>
            <FieldRef Name="ID" />
          </OrderBy>
        </Query>
      </View>
    </Views>
    <Forms>
      <Form Type="DisplayForm" Url="DispForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
      <Form Type="EditForm" Url="EditForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
      <Form Type="NewForm" Url="NewForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
    </Forms>
  </MetaData>
</List>
```

**Any help will Appreciate.**

Comment: Is 'Allow management of content types' set under Advanced settings?

Comment: Allow management of content types? Check Yes

Comment: Thanks.
As you can see Schema.xml file I have set "EnableContentTypes="TRUE"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this issue and was able to fix it as below:

You needn't specify `LinkTitle` name, its not needed.

In `schema.xml`, I changed the `ContentTypeRef` to `ContentType` and added the fields

Modify the `content type` tag in **elements.xml** as below:

```
<ContentType ID="0x010042D0C1C200A14B6887742B6344675C8B" 
            Name="Cost Center" 
            Group="SPFx Content Types" 
            Inherits="FALSE"
            Description="Sample content types from web part solution">
        <FieldRefs>
            <RemoveFieldRef ID="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}" />
            <FieldRef ID="{060E50AC-E9C1-4D3C-B1F9-DE0BCAC300F6}" /> 
            <FieldRef ID="{943E7530-5E2B-4C02-8259-CCD93A9ECB18}" />
        </FieldRefs>
    </ContentType>
```

Modify the **schema.xml** as below:

```
<List xmlns:ows="Microsoft SharePoint" Title="SPFxList" EnableContentTypes="TRUE" FolderCreation="FALSE" Direction="$Resources:Direction;" Url="Lists/SPFxList" BaseType="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <MetaData>
    <ContentTypes>
      <ContentType Name="Cost Center" ID="0x010042D0C1C200A14B6887742B6344675C8B" Group="SPFx Content Types" Inherits="FALSE">
        <FieldRefs>          
          <FieldRef ID="{060E50AC-E9C1-4D3C-B1F9-DE0BCAC300F6}" /> 
          <FieldRef ID="{943E7530-5E2B-4C02-8259-CCD93A9ECB18}" />          
        </FieldRefs>
      </ContentType>
    </ContentTypes>
    <Fields></Fields>
    <Views>..rest of your code
```

After that, bundle,package, upload and deploy the solution.

It will show up the correct content type in your list. The `Title` field will be "hidden" from the new/edit forms as well as your content type.